# Does stored function roll back the entire transaction?, is there an error in the documentation?

Tags: sql, mysql, transactions, stored-functions

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html

> If a SELECT statement within a transaction calls a stored function,
> and a statement within the stored function fails, **that statement** rolls
> back. If ROLLBACK is executed for the transaction subsequently, the
> entire transaction rolls back.

Could you give me an example of that part of the documentation?

From my understanding if the stored function fails the **whole transaction** will fail, not just the `SELECT a_stored_function();`

I am confused, is there an error in the documentation?

Comment: I believe the answer to this question is at your finger tips. It involves a fairly simple test which you can do yourself

Comment: Sure, but then the documentation is buggy, right? @RiggsFolly

Comment: So when you find the answer, I am sure the documentors would be more than happy for you to provide them a suggested amendment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table t (
  id serial primary key,
  word text
);

delimiter ;;

create function f(p_v text) returns int
no sql
begin
  declare v varchar(3);

  set v = p_v;

  return 0;
end;;

delimiter ;

start transaction;

insert into t (word) values ('bird');

select f('too long');

commit;

select * from t;
```

This deliberately causes an error in the function, by trying to stuff an 8-character string into a local variable that is `varchar(3)`. It's too long, so it causes an error when we call the function with that argument:

```
ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'v' at row 1
```

Does this roll back the `INSERT` done during the same transaction? The proof would be when we `SELECT` after committing the transaction.

Result:

```
select * from t;
+----+------+
| id | word |
+----+------+
|  1 | bird |
+----+------+
```

The `INSERT` was not rolled back. Only the single statement that called the function with the error was rolled back ("rolling back" a `SELECT` has no observable effect).

P.S.: This kind of quick proof of concept test is something you should be able to do yourself as a programmer. I think that's what the comments from RiggsFolly above were getting at.

Comment: so, this happens when the stored function *itself* fails, right?, i.e. if an `INSERT` within the stored function fails then the whole transaction fails, right? @Bill Karwin

Comment: I like your example @Bill Karwin

Comment: I encourage you to develop more tests!

Comment: Excellent, with this example I will do more